# Asynchronous method C# WhenAll issue

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Recently I ran into a problem with calling Asynchronous method.
Here is the code:

```
ClassA storage = new ClassA();// this is member of the class

async Task<ClassA> InitClassAObject(){ // async method of the class


    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>(); // create list task
        taskList.Add(Func1());
        taskList.Add(Func2());
        taskList.Add(Func3());            

        await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray()); // wait for all task done

        return storage; // <--- this line never be hit
 }

 async Task Func1(){
        await Task.Run(() =>{
          //update property A of storage
          //example storage.A = GetDataFromSomeWhere();
   });
 }

 async Task Func2(){
        await Task.Run(() =>{
          //update property B of storage
          //example storage.B = GetDataFromSomeWhereElse();
   });
 }
 ...
```

Question 1: The method InitClassAObject() never returns. Breakpoint at "return  never" hit.

Question 2: If I call multiple async method and they update different properties of the object ClassA. Is it safe to do so?

I've searched around for a solution but still not found. 
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe all the tasks never complete?

Comment: Did you debug what `Func1`, `Func2` and `Func3` do? If `return storage` _never_ gets hit, then probably because at least one of those tasks doesn't complete.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This used to work when I call synchronously Func1(); Funct2();.. Then I switch to this approach and it does not work anymore. Then I suppose there is nothing wrong with those functions. However I will verify them again for sure.

Comment: @ĐứcToànDương Sounds like your tasks are waiting on each other to me.

Comment: what objects your return from `Func1()` and `Func2()` ?

Comment: Sorry Guys, I found out that one of my funct() is throwing an exception which because of my input mistake. It works now when I add try-catch block to the functions. Howerver, can anyone let me know of the Question 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About Question 2: It's safe to update different properties. But you should keep in mind that if you read SomeProperty in Task1 and modify it in Task2 result will be unpredictable (Task1 may read before or after Task2 write)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are using the same source(object) because of that can cause deadlock? can you please not use same object and see result?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've found that one of my code failed to complete. By the way, though it works now, I am still afraid that asynchronously modifying (different properties) of the object can cause problems.